# Collapse column sideways (jerky transition/animation issue) using Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

So at it's simplest form, i have a Bootstrap 4 website and i'm trying to utilise it's collapse utility to collapse one of my two columns sideways. I have it working, but unfortunately the transition is animating the div from top to bottom causing a clunky effect - i need it to animate right to left (and vice versa for the toggle).

Please see my code below & JsFiddle example:

```
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="left-content" class="col-5 border collapse show">
        Collapsible Area
      </div>
      <div class="col border border-primary">
      <p>
        Variable width content
      </p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#left-content">Toggle Collapse</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7wuudd64/6/

Comment: Looks like it is changing the height, which is going to give you that clunky look. Think you're going to have to use something different. I would try max-height. An example can be found here https://codepen.io/LFeh/pen/ICkwe but this is going to require you to code it youself.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the question itself; linking to JSFiddle or CodePen is not adequate for "why isn't this code working"-style debugging questions.

Comment: I clearly added the html snippet in the question above - what else are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a CSS transition to your `#left` container, it can ease the effect.

```
.col-5.border.collapse {
    transition: height 1s ease; 
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7wuudd64/12/

*If my answer did help solve your issue, I'd really appreciate the upvote, thank you.*

Comment: Please provide the solution in the answer itself; when JSFiddle goes down your answer will not be useful anymore.

Comment: bludocto - I need the 'left-contain' to collapse from right to left not bottom to top. I tried swapping the height with width in the css, but unfortunately that didn't work for me.

Comment: TylerH - again he did provide the snippet, plus the jsfiddle is very helpful aswell and used all the time on StackOverflow.